# how to assign weight to Spinner programatically using Android without using LinearLayout?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-spinner

i have tried this code but its not dynamically setting the Spinner Weight.

```
 <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/enterdevice_filter1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/dropdown_small"
                    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" />


 LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
                                 LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
spinner.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Inserting weight at the end of this LOC after Wrap_content braces closed gives me no result.

```
 spinner.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 spinner.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
 LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
```

Use this type of LayoutParam parameters.
Here **1f** represent the weight of a view in parent layout.

Comment: i don't want using LinearLayout can i do it without Linear Layout

Comment: there is spinner inside linearLayout and setting its weight